# Why can there be const assignment operators

Tags: c++, c++23

With C++23 there will be

```
std::pair<T1, T1>::operator =( const pair &other ) const;
```

For me an assignment-operator operating on const-objects doesn't make any sense since the object can't be modified. Why will C++23 have this operator on pair ? And even more confusing, there's:

```
std::pair<T1, T1>::operator =( pair &&other ) const;
```

[EDIT]: This won't work because what this points to will be const:

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    void operator +=( T x ) const;
    T m_x;
};

template<typename T>
void S<T>::operator +=( T x ) const
{
    m_x += x;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    S<int> si;
    si += 1;
}
```

So why is there a const-qualified assignment-operator with pair ?

Comment: It makes sense for pairs of non-const references.

Comment: this happened because of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html#a-tuple-that-is-writable

Answer (score 11):

It makes sense for pairs of non-const references. Those remain assignable even when `const`. Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(const T x) {x = 42;}

int main()
{
    int y = 1;
    foo<int &>(y);
    std::cout << y << '\n'; // 42
}
```

---

But why bother supporting it in `std::pair`?

I've recently seen an explanation somewhere on SO, but can't find the link ([found it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63412623/2752075)). It went along the lines of:

- You're making a generic algorithm, and you're assigning to a function result in a template (such as to a dereferenced iterator). If the function happens to return by value, you can silently get unexpected behavior (assignment doing nothing).
- You would like a compilation error instead, but virtually nobody
  `&`-qualifies their assignment operators.
- Then a logical next step is to check the return type and reject non-references.
- But you want to leave a loophole. E.g. dereferencing `std::vector<bool>` iterator returns (a proxy object) by value, and assigning to it should be allowed.
- You could invent a type trait for it, but there's a clever alternative. You check if the assignment still compiles if you add `const` to the return type. If it doesn't, you raise a compilation error. This generalizes nicely to returning references, since adding `const` to them leaves the type unchanged (and still assignable, if the reference was non-const).
- To make it work, you need to add `const` to assignment operators of all such types (and it was done for [`std::vector<bool>::reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference)).
- As for why `std::pair` (and `std::tuple`) need it: iterators from [`std::views::zip()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view) dereference to tuples of references, and you want to be able to assign to those tuples.

But I don't remember which standard algorithms are going to be constrained like this in C++23. Probably something in ranges...

Comment: For the OP example, you'd need `void operator+=(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type const& x) const` to accommodate `S<int&>`.