Allowing STL algorithms to swap when iterators dereference to a wrapper class (i.e. an rvalue)
I am implementing a C++ wrapper for a C library that has a "vector of vectors" container. In the C++ interface, I would like iterators to dereference not to a raw C pointer, but to a convenient wrapper class (that otherwise acts as a reference).
With this approach, iterators dereference to an rvalue. This seems to prevent algorithms like std::sort() or std::reverse() from working, as swap expects lvalues.
Is there any way to allow such a container to work with STL algorithms, while still letting iterators dereference to a wrapper class instead of a true reference (&) to the underlying raw data?
I tried providing friend void iter_swap(iterator it1, iterator i2) within my iterator class (just like here), but std::reverse / std::sort still doesn't work. I get an error which refers to the instantiation of the std::iter_swap (not the iter_swap I provided). Note that using std::iter_swap; iter_swap(a, b); does work.
This answer suggests an that ADL-based customization of iter_swap can be made use of the standard library in principle, currently prominent implementations have very limited support for this. Is there any alternative that I can use?
Update: Providing swap(Foo &&, Foo &&), where Foo is the wrapper "reference type", allows this to work. What will go wrong if I use this approach?
References:

Can iter_swap be specialised?
specializing std::swap for rvalues (suggests specializing std::iter_swap directly, but as I understand, this is risky?)


@user17732522 OK, give me some time to create a minimal example.

@user17732522 Here's a draft minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/W8ExWrr7h Let me know if this is clear before I edit it into the main post.

With this approach, iterators dereference to an rvalue. I don't think it's true. The wrapper is a temporary rvalue that can't be bound to a non const lvalue reference.

I take back what I said earlier. This can already not work, because the legacy forward iterator concept requires that * returns a (const) reference to the value type, which in your example must be int, not IntRef the proxy. However, I think the new C++20 iterator concepts are more flexible and should be workable with the std::ranges algorithms.

For what it's worth, if I replace the bulk of your code with using IntRef = std::reference_wrapper<int>; and using MyContainer = std::vector<IntRef>;, the standard reference wrapper and vector container work.  Might be a useful data point.

The legacy forward iterator concept requires that * returns a reference to the value type.
Both std::sort and std::reverse require the iterator to be a forward iterator or stronger.
So whether or not you can make your proxy type or iterator swappable doesn't even matter. The algorithms have undefined behavior with your iterator type to begin with and the same is true for all legacy algorithms that require a forward iterator.
The C++20 iterator concepts used for the std::ranges algorithms are more flexible and in particular the C++20 std::forward_iterator concept does not require * to return a reference. It should be possible to make it work for std::ranges::sort and std::ranges::reverse.
In order to achieve this you will need to go through all the std::bidirectional_iterator and std::permutable concepts (for std::ranges::reverse) or std::random_access_iterator and std::sortable concepts (for std::ranges::sort) to see what you need to implement.

Thank you, these pointers are quite helpful. "You will also need to make the proxy type implicitly convertible to a reference to the value type" Does this mean that having the value_type and reference be the same is not going to work? While this may sound strange, it comes from the design of the C library I am trying to wrap. Anyway, let's drop that complication. Here's another question that I was considering asking separately, but perhaps it's better to ask here first:

I am having trouble satisfying std::implicitly_writable, which is a requirement for permutable / sortable. Here's a minimal example that I believe satisfies the requirements you mentioned: https://godbolt.org/z/7YW98G78o  implicitly_writable is satisfied only if I add a constant assignment operator to the reference type. But this seems to make no sense: something that is constant should not be assignable. Is adding this truly necessary (and if so, why?) or am I missing another way to make this work?

I'm sorry, I meant indirectly_writable of course. It also does not work if I use std::reference_wrapper<int> instead of IntRef. I am baffled by what indirectly_writable is supposed to be, conceptually.

@Szabolcs Sorry, maybe my initial suggestions for how to go about implementing it weren't good. Honestly, I do not have much experience with implementing this kind of iterator. Unfortunately I do not have time right now to go through it to check what you are missing. How to achieve indirectly_writable might be a good question on its own.

I think my question is mostly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63413121/695132 Thanks for the help so far, it was quite helpful!
